# Terminal for android

Tags: samsung, stock-android, android-emulator

I'm still learning how to use the terminal. I know the dangers of fiddling with it. But I want to use the terminal emulator app to navigate my phone(messaging, camera, launch applications, etc) from the command line. What are the commands and where should I start

Comment: Do you want to run apps via comman line?

Comment: If it's possible, yes. I'd like to be able to, say I get a text. Instead of tapping the messages icon, I want to be able to enter something into the command line  and the app opens. Kinda like if you type( gnome-system-monitor. ) the processes menu pops up on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to take a [Nandroid backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/48833/96277) (requires a [custom Recovery](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/All_About_Recovery_Images)) first if you've had an unpleasing incident on some other OS, or want to recover from one after fiddling with terminal on Android.

> I want to use the terminal emulator app to navigate my phone(messaging, camera, launch applications, [and so on).]

Messaging and Camera (UI not HW) are also apps in Android and are accessed in the manner similar to other apps (they have their `.apk` in `/system/app`). The most common way to access an app is to call its component or activity using `am` command. Consider [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110812/96277) as an example to use `am`. See more examples on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) like:

- [How to start an Android application from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613889/how-to-start-an-android-application-from-the-command-line)
- [How to run a specific Android app using Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494764/how-to-run-a-specific-android-app-using-terminal)
- [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

`am` will only launch a part of the app and possibly would need root access if called without ADB(has higher privilege then a normal user). So how would you interact with the app from command line?

For that, I prefer to use Android keyevent or Pointer location (under **Developer options**) combined with the `input` command.  See:

- [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)
- [How to use ADB to send touch events to device using sendevent command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437686/how-to-use-adb-to-send-touch-events-to-device-using-sendevent-command)

You would now be able to launch an app with UI and can use the app rather easily from command-line.

> What are the commands?

I'm not aware of all the commands but you can take a look at `/system/bin` and `/systen/xbin` (like `/bin` and `/sbin` in GNU/Linux). You'll need root access to use some of them. (See [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) too.)

> Where should I start?

Well, I'm unaware of a crash-course and I would advise to work on an issue or a possibility to learn the *know-how* of terminal rather easily. Try [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111228/109933) for a start.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try your hand on [Qpython](http://qpython.com/)
Basically QPython is a script engine which runs Python programs on android devices.

It includes libraries like [SL4A](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) and [Android Helper](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/detail?name=androidhelper.py) which can do all the things you mentioned via its terminal.

You can also install only SL4A
[HERE](http://www.pythoncentral.io/python-for-android-the-scripting-layer-sl4a/) is information about it.
An excerpt from site on installation

> SL4A is really easy to install. The application is distributed as an APK, the standard format for Android apps, so it can be installed in the same way. However, before installing apps from 'unknown sources', you need to allow that on your device. If you haven't already, open your device's main Settings menu, open the Security menu, then "allow installation of non-Market apps" by checking the Unknown Sources option. Now you're ready to install the Scripting Layer.